ADF: Convert csv text to json
In Azure data factory, I get a response as a string and it is a csv formatted.  But with the caveat.
The data looks like this
Amount,Date,Code,Hours,SourceSystem\r\n0,2024-10-14 00:00:00,HOL,8,106\r\n0,2024-03-1 00:00:00,HLL,45,2,106\r\n0,2024-12-15 00:00:00,AAA,2,106\r\n0,2024-10-14 00:00:00,HOL,53,106\r\n

As seen, there are \r\n in there separating the "row" as if imagined in a csv file.
My goal is to take that string, and convert it to Json array looking like
[
{
  "Amount":"0",
  "Date":"2024-10-14 00:00:00",
  "Code":"HOL",
  "Hours":"8",
  "SourceSystem":"106"
},
{
  "Amount":"0",
  "Date":"2024-10-14 00:00:00",
  "Code":"HOL",
  "Hours":"8",
  "SourceSystem":"106"
},
{
  "Amount":"0",
  "Date":"2024-10-14 00:00:00",
  "Code":"HOL",
  "Hours":"8",
  "SourceSystem":"106"
},
]

I am not sure if I understand at what step and how to convert or escape the "\r\n" in the original string.

If the rows in your CSV file are less than 5000 rows, you can try the below approach.
First give the expression @string('\\n') as Row delimiter in the csv dataset. I had tried to set the \r\n as Row delimiter but it didn't work even by the dynamic expression as well. So, I came up with this workaround. Make sure the schema is clear in your dataset.

In the pipeline, give this dataset to a lookup activity and uncheck the First Row only in that. The output of the lookup activity will give a JSON array with including a string\\114\\ in the last column SourceSystem. If not this, obeserve what extra string it is adding by the preview of the dataset. Remove this string and it will be your required output JSON array.
Use the below expression in an Array type set variable activity.
@json(replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'\\114\\',''))


Result JSON array:

You can store this JSON array in a file using copy activity. Go through this SO answer to know more about it.
If it is more than 5000 rows, you can use a Mapping dataflow in ADF to achieve your requirement.
Give the same dataset to a dataflow source and import the projection in the source. Use select transformation to remove the \r in the last column name and use the Derived column transformation with expression replace(SourceSystem,'\\r','') to remove \r in the rows of the column. Add JSON dataset as a sink and it will give the desired result.

Thank you.  This is great.  However, this would be my step 2.  For the step 1, I don't have the content in the blob storage YET.  I get it as a part of a response from the web activity, So, it is stored in a variable.  I am attempting to write that response to the file.  And it works, i use 'copy activity' with the 'dummy' source, and 'additional column' that is read from that variable.
The file gets written, however it gets written as a single cell - that is csv nature is ignored, and the whole content, with the header is included in a single table cell

Let me know if my approach works or not.
